# Get docker logs to show chinese characters

Tags: docker, logging

While running a cron in PHP, i use `error_logs` to output to docker logs and this is what I see.

```
[Tue Apr 16 02:21:58.311782 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 16] [client 172.21.0.7:50328] >>>>>>>>>>article imported: \xe4\xbd\xbf\xe7\x94\xa8\xe6\x89\x8b\xe6\x9c\xba\xe6\x88\x96\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x8e\x9f\xe5\x9b\xa0\xe4\xb9\x8b\xe4\xb8\x80 \xe7\xbe\x8e\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe4\xba\xba\xe6\xad\xbb\xe4\xba\xa1\xe4\xba\xba\xe6\x95\xb0\xe5\x88\x9b\xe6\x96\xb0\xe9\xab\x98(934602)
```

I am expecting Chinese characters instead of these unicode. Is there a way to get docker logs to display utf8 instead?

Comment: Have u achieved that already? I think maybe u did not execute decoding when writing logs. I'm not familiar with PHP, but in Python, it supports multiple languages. Since it could do encoding and decoding automatically at right time. In your case, Python VM would decode log into utf-8 when writing logs.

Comment: yeah i achieve that. Cant remember how though. Think I need to set env lang as UTF8